# To split fullname into Salutation,Firstname and lastname in java

Tags: java, string, split

I am receiving full name, i need to split this into **Salutation, Firstname and lastname**.
for eg.

- Steve Emond==> Steve as Firstname , Emond as lastname(here Salutation is Empty)
- Mr Chris Barker  ==> Mr as Salutation, Chris as Firstname , Barker as lastname
- Justin ==> Justin as lastname(Salutation  and Firstname are empty)

**Note:** received Miss,Mr,Mrs as Salutation values.

Code:

```
 String FirstName="";
 String fullName="Barker";
String[] nameArray=fullName.split(" ");
if(nameArray.length<3)
{
    System.out.println("Salutation: " + nameArray[0]);
    System.out.println("LastName: " + nameArray[1]);
    System.out.println("FirstName: " + FirstName);
}else if(nameArray.length>=3){
    System.out.println("Salutation: " + nameArray[0]);
    System.out.println("LastName: " + nameArray[nameArray.length - 1]);
    for (int index = 1; index < nameArray.length - 1; index++) {
        FirstName = FirstName + " " + nameArray[index];
     }
    System.out.println("FirstName: " + FirstName.trim());
}
```

The above code works fine when all values given in input( ie Mr Chris Barker ), for the remaining case it failed. can anyone provide me the solution for this?

Comment: use Pattern and Matcher with groups in this cases

Comment: Hi @YCF_L,
Thanks for your answer. can you please share some code snippet to match this case which would be very helpful for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1:

```js
    String fullName="Steve Emond";
  String[] nameArray=fullName.split(" ");
  if(nameArray.length==1)
  {
   System.out.println("LastName: " + nameArray[0]);
     
  }else if(nameArray.length==2){
   System.out.println("FirstName: " + nameArray[0]);
   System.out.println("LastName: " + nameArray[1]);      
  }
  else if(nameArray.length==3){
   System.out.println("Salutation: " + nameArray[0]);
   System.out.println("FirstName: " + nameArray[1]);
   System.out.println("LastName: " + nameArray[2]);      
  }
```

Using Regex Method 2:

```js
String fullName="Mr Justin raj Savarimuthu";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(new String ("(Mr\\s|Miss\\s|Mrs\\s)"));
  
  if(fullName.matches("(Mr\\s|Miss\\s|Mrs\\s).*"))
  {
   System.out.println("Salutation:"+fullName.substring(0,fullName.indexOf(' ')));
   fullName=pattern.split(fullName)[1].trim();
  }
  
  String[] parts = fullName.split(" ");
  String firstName="";
  for(int i=0;i<parts.length-1;i++)
  {
   firstName=firstName+parts[i]+" ";
  }
        if(firstName!="")
         System.out.println("FirstName:"+firstName);
        System.out.println("LastName:"+parts[parts.length-1]);
```

Comment: Hi @Harsh,
Thank you so much for your reply. your answer is very helpful. for eg. Justin raj Savarimuthu, in the above example we get Justin as Salutation. is there any way to use regex for Salutation to the above code like @ YCF_L suggested? please let me know

Comment: Hey @Justin I have made edits and added a Mehtod 2,See if it helps.

Comment: What about `Mrshan Smith` as name ?

Comment: Hi @HarshYadav,
I have used Mehtod 2 for Salutation identification, that was really helpful for me, Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @HarshYadav,
if Invalid Salutation present in Name(eg. ABC. Mihaela Green), matches happen and will lead to exception like " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at JavaPackage.FullnameSplitter.main(FullnameSplitter.java:14)". Can u pls check with input(ABC. Mihaela Green).

Comment: Hi @Justin..I didn't clearly get you .Do u want to handle the Invalid Salutation?
You can surround it with a try catch block and in catch block u can say something like "Invalid Input".